# How to forward a webhook message to another server?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm trying to forward an embed that a webhook sends a message in the server. Once it sends the embed the bot immediately sends it to the other server but it shows this error

discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message

here is my code

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    
    if message.webhook_id:
        msg = message.content
        channel = client.get_channel(760182149839716423)
        await channel.send(msg)
```

Answer (score 1):

An **embed** can be found in [`message.embeds`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message.embeds), which contains a list of all embeds attached to this message. `message.content` is the actual text from the message, which in the case of an Embed-only message is nothing. This means you're trying to send an empty string (`""`), which you can't do.

```py
# Check if this message is a webhook AND has embeds
if message.webhook_id and message.embeds:
    embed = message.embeds[0]
    channel = client.get_channel(760182149839716423)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

`embed = message.embeds[0]` assumes it's the first embed in the list, but most messages usually only have one so this should be fine.